# How to translate the cursor position alongside scaling the projection matrix Opengl

Tags: java, opengl, matrix

I am working with with LWJGL and I am looking to select tiles after scaling the projection matrix but I am not sure how. I am using JOML for the linear algebra library. The projection matrix is first having an Ortho transformation applied, then it is translated to the player's positions, and lastly it is scaled. When I scale the projection matrix since everything is zoomed in the mouse no longer selects the correct tile. This was my attempt to correct for the mouse position:

```
 float cursorX = input.getCursorPosX() + getX();
 float cursorY = input.getCursorPosY(true) + getY();
 cursorX *= (1/cameraScalar);
 cursorY *= (1/cameraScalar);
```

The first two lines gets the cursor from GLFW and adds the player position to it. The third and fourth lines just multiply by the inverse of the camera scale.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JOML, but the general approach for what you want to do is something like this:

1. transform real screen coords in pixels to OpenGL screen coordinate system, which is a cube sitting at (0,0,0) with sides of length 2 (you will probably need to invert Y axis):

   `float screenX = 2.0f * mouseX / screenWidth - 1.0f;
    float screenY = 1.0f - 2.0f * mouseY / screenHeight;`
2. project screen vector with coords (screenX, screenY, 1) to the world using inverse of projection matrix (`proj`):

   `Vector3 screen = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 1);
   Vector3 world = proj.inverse().mul(screen);`
3. Now `world.x` and `world.y` contains correct world coordinates

Answer (score 0):

JOML provides GLU's "unproject" function and an additional "[unprojectRay](http://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Matrix4f.html#unprojectRay-float-float-int:A-org.joml.Vector3f-org.joml.Vector3f-)".